# Name of UI component when submitting a review on iOS Apple App Store from iOS

Tags: ios, dialog, popup, app-store, alert

Does anybody knows what is the name of this component on iOS (see below)?

This is shown when you rate an app on the Apple App Store, I think in other places too just that I cannot remember right now.

I would have assumed this is a native component just that I am having troubles to find it, not sure what search terms to use to avoid all the results about SKStoreReviewController and similar.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not built in, but there's a library [SPAlert](https://github.com/varabeis/SPAlert) that can do this.

Comment: I was hopping it is built in, but anyways, thank you!